# computing some expected values using Bounded convergence theorem

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X\ge 0$ but do not assume $E(1/X) < \infty$. Show that
$$ \lim_{y\to \infty}yE\left(\frac{1}{X}1_{X>y}\right)=0$$
$$ \lim_{y\to 0}yE\left(\frac{1}{X}1_{X>y}\right)=0$$

Note that $y E\left(\frac{1}{X}1_{X>y}\right)\le 1$. Thus I think that Bounded Convergence Theorem would help. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, use:
$$y E\left(\frac1 X I_{X>y}\right) \le \Pr(X>y) $$
For the second problem, given $\epsilon>0$, find $y_1>0$ so that $\Pr(0<X<y_1) < \epsilon$.  If $y < \epsilon y_1$, then
$$ y E\left(\frac1 X I_{X>y} \right) = y E\left(\frac1 X I_{y < X< y_1} \right) + y E\left(\frac1 X I_{X\ge y_1} \right) \\
 \le \Pr(y<X<y_1) + \epsilon y_1 E\left(\frac1 X I_{X\ge y_1} \right) \le 2 \epsilon .$$